# SQL Loader - Load data using TERMINATED into different table

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

For example, in the feed file i got Data like this

```
HEADER|AB|C|DATAHERE
DETAIL|DATA1|DATA2|DATA3
DETAIL|DATA1|DATA2|DATA3
DETAIL|DATA1|DATA2|DATA3
DETAIL|DATA1|DATA2|DATA3
FOOTER|COUNTER
```

Line one should insert into tableHeader
Line 2 to line 5 should be insert into tableDetail
and the last line should be insert into tableFooter

here is me sqlloader script

```
Load DATA
REPLACE INTO TABLE tableHeader
WHEN (1:6) = 'HEADER'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    COL1 FILLER,
    COL2 FILLER,
    COL3 FILLER,
    HEADER_DETAIL,
)


INTO TABLE tableDetail
WHEN (1:6) = 'DETAIL'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    A FILLER,
    DATA1,
    DATA2,
    DATA3
)

INTO TABLE tableFooter
WHEN (1:6) = 'FOOTER'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    Z FILLER,
    FOOTER_DETAIL
)
```

The data inserted into tableHeader is correct, but the data insert into other table is all go mess... can anyone give me a hand on this?

Comment: "all go mess" isn't very helpful. Please add the table DDL and what actually gets inserted into each table.

Comment: for example, for table details, the inserted data in DATA1 column is null, DATA2 column is DATA1, data in DATA3 column is DATA2

Comment: in fact... it can be all null....very hard to describe... because the extract testing data is different with the sample i post out, but can confirm, other than the first table data is correct, the rest of the table's (tableDetails and tableFooter in this example)  data is incorrect mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical record assembly is confused. This is [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1129):

> ... Field scanning does not start over from the beginning of the record for a new INTO TABLE clause. Instead, scanning continues where it left off.
>
> To force record scanning to start in a specific location, you use the POSITION parameter.

So you can identify the first filler field length with `POSITION(1:7)`:

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE INTO TABLE tableHeader
WHEN (1:6) = 'HEADER'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    COL1 FILLER,
    COL2 FILLER,
    COL3 FILLER,
    HEADER_DETAIL
)
INTO TABLE tableDetail
WHEN (1:6) = 'DETAIL'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    A FILLER POSITION(1:7),
    DATA1,
    DATA2,
    DATA3
)
INTO TABLE tableFooter
WHEN (1:6) = 'FOOTER'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    Z FILLER POSITION(1:7),
    FOOTER_DETAIL
)
```

This loads your sample data into the correct fields in some dummy tables I created. Without those position specifications only the header was loaded with the rest discarded as all null; with the position as 1:6 the data went into the wrong columns, which I think is what you were describing.

You could use a named field for your `WHEN` but the delimiter may need to be included:

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE INTO TABLE tableHeader
WHEN RECTYPE = 'HEADER|'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    RECTYPE FILLER POSITION(1:7),
    FILL1 FILLER,
    FILL2 FILLER,
    HEADER_DETAIL
)
INTO TABLE tableDetail
WHEN RECTYPE = 'DETAIL|'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    RECTYPE FILLER POSITION(1:7),
    DATA1,
    DATA2,
    DATA3
)
INTO TABLE tableFooter
WHEN RECTYPE = 'FOOTER|'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    RECTYPE FILLER POSITION(1:7),
    FOOTER_DETAIL
)
```